# Multigraph reduction in O(m+n) time

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, big-o

Consider a multigraph G, where the following three reductions need to be made:

1. Vertices with two neighbors are removed from the graph and their neighbors joined to each other via a new edge.
2. Vertices with one neighbor are removed from the graph.
3. Duplicate edges are removed from the graph.

This is a homework question that I had on a recent assignment, where I am asked to show that these three reductions can be done in O(m+n) time. Any help to better understand how to go about doing this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you think of a way to get any of those three reductions done in `O(n+m)` time? What data structures would be appropriate for tracking and updating vertex degrees, and finding all degree 1 or 2 vertices quickly?

Comment: My thought is that I could use a hash table to map vertices to degrees. Once I locate the vertices with degree 2, I can remove that vertex easily, and I don't need to change the degrees of the other two that i just connected because they each lose a degree to the vertex that was just deleted but they each gain a degree by connecting to each other. Then I could find the vertices with degree 1 and reduce the degree of their neighbors. Lastly, I could traverse what remains and hash each vertex's edges to a set to get rid of duplicate edges.

Comment: That's close to all you need. However, the order of the three reductions is important, especially for proving runtime. There is one (and only one) way to order those three operations so that you can always finish each operation in a single batch. For example, getting rid of duplicate edges might create new degree-2 vertices.

Comment: Hmm that's a good point. Along the same line though, if i remove duplicates first before finding the 2-degree vertices, I could run into the same problem if I delete a 2-degree vertex and connect the two neighbors and the neighbors were already connected. That being said, as I think aloud, I could always do a check before creating the new edge, i.e., only join the neighbors if they are not already joined. Then I could start with the duplicates, then 2-degree, then 1-degree. Does that make sense?

Comment: You're right, my statement is technically wrong unless you test for connectedness of neighbors when you delete a degree-2-vertex. Still you'll want to do duplicates, then 1-degree, then 2-degree (since deleting a 1-degree vertex can create 2-degree vertices).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the help! Anything else I need? Also, can you respond as an answer so I can accept? Thanks

Comment: What are m and n?

Comment: In this case the vertices and edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reduction isn't unique: consider a graph with two vertices and one edge, `v-w`, which has two possible reductions. I will explain how to get an arbitrary valid reduction.

You'll first want to remove duplicate edges: this can be done using a set or a hash-table to identify duplicates, in `O(n+m)` time. I'll assume you're storing the graph as a dictionary from vertices to their adjacency sets.

After this, you'll want to iterate over the vertices, and keep a set (or any container with `O(1)` membership testing) to store 'to be deleted' vertices. After this first pass over vertices, this will contain any vertices with degree 1 or 2.

Now, while your 'to be deleted' set isn't empty, you'll:

- Pop a vertex `v` from the set.
- If `v` has degree 0, ignore it.
- If `v` has degree 1 and its neighbor is `w`, delete `v` from your graph and remove `v` from `w's` adjacency set. If `w` now has degree `1` or `2` and isn't in the 'to be deleted' set, add it to the set.

Otherwise, `v` has degree `2`, and two distinct neighbors `u, w`.

- If `u` and `w` are not adjacent: add an edge from `u` to `w`, remove `v` and its edges from your graph.
- If `u` and `w` are adjacent: remove `v` and its edges from your graph. If `u` or `w` now have degree `1` or `2`, add them to the 'to be deleted' set.

This does constant work per vertex and edge, but relies upon a certain graph representation of 'adjacency sets' where edges can be deleted in constant time. Converting to and from this representation, given adjacency lists or a list of edges, can be done in `O(m+n)` time.